# After Updating Android Studio to version 4.1 Cause: duplicate entry: META-INF/new_core_debug.kotlin_module this error is happening?How to fix

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, build.gradle, android-manifest

This is the Android studio version

```
Android Studio 4.1
Build #AI-201.8743.12.41.6858069, built on September 23, 2020
Runtime version: 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b01 amd64
VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
Windows 10 10.0
GC: ParNew, ConcurrentMarkSweep
Memory: 1237M
Cores: 16
Registry: ide.new.welcome.screen.force=true
Non-Bundled Plugins: org.jetbrains.kotlin, com.developerphil.adbidea
```

This is the Error Message

Execution failed for task ':new_core:bundleLibCompileDebug'.

> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
> duplicate entry: META-INF/new_core_debug.kotlin_module

How do i solve this

I tried this solution

```
packagingOptions {
        exclude("META-INF/new_core_debug.kotlin_module")
    }
```

but same issue happened.

Comment: I'm having exactly the same issue!

Comment: still stuck at the issue and couldnt apply the firebase crashlytics now

Answer (score 0):

have you tried doing a `./gradlew clean assumbleDebug --rerun-tasks`?